# HighCharts offline-exporting module not working

Tags: highcharts

I'm having trouble forcing highcharts to export offline.  I've added the offline-exporting.js module along with the exporting module.  I've set the fallbackToExportServer to false, but I still go to the highcharts server (https://export.highcharts.com/) and get this error:  13 Request Entity Too Large.

```
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>


exporting: {
      filename: title,
      fallbackToExportServer: false,
```

To see the issue, go to: https://www.nrel.gov/transportation/drive-cycle-tool/

In the Drive cycles table, search for “Fleet DNA”.
Click on “Fleet DNA Drayage Maximum Energy*”
Scroll up and click “Download Drive Cycle Data or Image” under the chart.
Choose “Download JPEG image”

Some data sets work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is linked to this reported issue:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4614

As a workaround you could set up a custom exporting server with increased size limit:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't the https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export work as well? That's what I'm trying but something must be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue few days back, kind of strange, despite setting the flag to false, it was calling the highchart server for chart pdf.

I then resorted to use exportChartLocal method of highchart chart instance:

```
chart.exportChartLocal({
     type: 'image/jpeg', // replace with image/jpeg
     filename: 'test.jpg',
     fallbackToExportServer: false,
     sourceWidth: 900,
     scale: 1,
});
```

Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/riteshwaghela/huw8e31z/7/

Comment: I tried that, but couldn't get it to work.  Do you have a working example out there somewhere?

Comment: @sfjeld - Check the link in the answer.